# Add CQL filter into GetFeatureInfo request in OpenLayers 2

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, cql-filter

I have made a WMS layer using OpenLayers 2 and GeoServer and I display the layer using a specific CQL filter.

Now I want to use a `WMSGetFeatureInfo` request in order to get specific data on click.
Although I use the CQL parameters in my `WMSGetFeatureInfo` request nothing seems to change and I get back all the results.

This is my code:

First I create the layer and added to the map:

```
        cql = "ftth_pop='"+ area+"' AND simul_desc='"+simulation+"'";
        layerName2 = 'ngn_marco:out_ducts';
        wms =  new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("wms","http://ngn-marco.enomix.gr/geo_wms/",
                {
                    layers: layerName2,
                    format:  "image/png",
                    transparent: true,
                    version: "1.1.1",
                    CQL_FILTER: cql,
                    tiled: true 
                },
                {
                    format: "image/png",
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    visibility: true
                }
        );  
        
       map.addLayer(wms);
```

Then I make the `WMSGetFeatureInfo` request:

```
      infoControls = {
        click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://ngn-marco.enomix.gr/geo_wms/', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            layer: wms,
            CQL_FILTER: cql,
            queryVisible: true
            })
        };
```

I add the control and activate it as:

```
    for (var i in infoControls) { 
        infoControls[i].events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
        map.addControl(infoControls[i]); 
    }

    infoControls.click.activate();
```

The showInfo() function is:

```
function showInfo(evt) {
        if (evt.features && evt.features.length) {
            highlightLayer.destroyFeatures();
            highlightLayer.addFeatures(evt.features);
            highlightLayer.redraw();
        } else {
            //console.log(evt.txt);
            document.getElementById('responseText').innerHTML = evt.text;
    }
    }
```

The problem is that the CQL filter for the `WMSGetFeatureInfo` request doesn't work.

**EDIT**

These are the parameters sent to GeoServer:

```
BBOX    2637105.178295,4616485.137413,2638971.913845,4617560.033123
FEATURE_COUNT   10
FORMAT  image/png
HEIGHT  900
INFO_FORMAT text/html
LAYERS  ngn_marco:out_ducts
QUERY_LAYERS    ngn_marco:out_ducts
REQUEST GetFeatureInfo
SERVICE WMS
SRS EPSG:900913
STYLES  
VERSION 1.1.1
WIDTH   1563
X   715
Y   325
```

And this is part of the response I get back:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Geoserver GetFeatureInfo output</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding:.2em .1em;
    }
    table.featureInfo th {
        padding:.2em .2em;
        font-weight:bold;
        background:#eee;
    }
    table.featureInfo td{
        background:#fff;
    }
    table.featureInfo tr.odd td{
        background:#eee;
    }
    table.featureInfo caption{
        text-align:left;
        font-size:100%;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:.2em .2em;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <table class="featureInfo">
        <caption class="featureInfo">out_ducts</caption>
        <tr>
          <th>fid</th>
            <th>ftth_pop</th>
            <th>simul_desc</th>
            <th>coverage</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>crossing</th>
            <th>ducts</th>
            <th>ductsdrop</th>
            <th>ductsdist</th>
            <th>ductsfeed</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>out_ducts.1627932</td>    
          <td>ATH_69</td>
          <td>PtP_test_1</td>
          <td>100</td>
          <td>2657</td>
          <td>false</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: does the getFeatureInfo request contain the CQL filter? if yes then we need to see the GeoServer log, if not then it is just an OpenLayers issue and you need to add some logging to your script

Comment: Yes the getFeatureInfo contains the CQL filter (its in the code above). And the geoserver log doesn't have an error. I was wondering perhaps my showInfo function might has some issue.

Comment: does the response from GeoServer look good?

Comment: Yes. The log files seems in order. No error messages.

Comment: That might just mean there is no error - what is in the response sent by the server to the client

Comment: Well I see the response from firebug. Its a huge object containing all the returning info:  {displayClass: "olControlWMSGetFeatureInfo", url: "http://ngn-marco.enomix.gr/geo_wms/", title: "identify features on click", layer: O…s.L…r.WMS.O…s.C…s.initialize, CQL_FILTER: "ftth_pop='ATH_69' AND simul_desc='PtP_test_1'"…}
CQL_FILTER: "ftth_pop='ATH_69' AND simul_desc='PtP_test_1'"
active: true
displayClass: "olControlWMSGetFeatureInfo"...

Comment: please use the edit button to modify your question with examples of the url requested and the response sent back

Comment: Here is a GetFeatureInfo request with CQL filter that works for the "states" demo layer: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&FORMAT=image/png&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&LAYERS=topp:states&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-109.1162,34.0576,-100.2392,42.9345&X=50&Y=50&QUERY_LAYERS=topp:states&TRANSPARENT=true&FEATURE_COUNT=50&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME=%27Colorado%27.  
It returns one hit, edit Colorado into Texas and you will get zero.

Comment: I edited as you said. I see now that in the parameters of the request there is no CQL attribute although I define it in the request

Comment: Please edit the title into something like "How to add CQL filter into GetFeatureInfo request in OpenLayers" because CQL filter does work if it is applied.

Comment: @user30184 I edited the titles. Can you please help me with the issue I have. For some reason the filter is not applied!

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty bad with javascript.

Comment: Has this problem been solved? I have the same type of problem and I would like an answer too (see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213694/openlayers-getfeatureinfo-shows-all-features-even-with-cql-filter)

Comment: I remember that it was a naming issue with the cql vendor parameter. Try to write it with lower case or test it also with one cql filter. Its something simply but I don't have the code right now to check how I fixed it!